# Empty promise return in ES6 using an imported class

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have a question about why my response is being returned and printed as undefined.

This is my method in my main.js:

```
find() {
        return this.serviceFactory
            .createRequest()
            .withId(333)
            .sendAsGet().then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
```

The above console.log(response) is where I am getting the undefined response;

and this is the imported class that is used as this.serviceFactory

```
export class ServiceFactory {
    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.http.baseUrl = serviceUrlParts.baseUrl;
        this.endpoint = "";
        this.id = "";
    }

    createRequest() {
        return this;
    }

    withId(id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    setEndPoint(endpoint){
        this.endpoint = serviceUrlParts.baseUrl + endpoint;
    }

    sendAsGet() {
        return this.http.get(`${this.endpoint}/${this.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                this.parseJSONContent(response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    parseJSONContent(response) {
        console.dir(JSON.parse(response.content));
        return JSON.parse(response.content);
    }
}
```

The console.dir(JSON.parse(response.content)) in the parseJSONContent method is printing out the correct object that is returned from the API.  Somewhere going back through to the call it is being lost.  Some insight into what is happening wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because you *do* return `undefined` (or, don't return anything) from all these callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you do not return the value:

```
.then(response => {
    this.parseJSONContent(response);
})
```

change it to:

```
.then(response => {
    return this.parseJSONContent(response);
})
```

or

```
.then(response => this.parseJSONContent(response))
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you Tamas, that makes perfect sense lol.   I went with the "or" option you posted but they all both worked correctly.  Will mark as answer asap.